# Winmerge identical file names with different extension

Tags: winmerge

Can Winmerge be used to compare two folders that have the same files, but different extensions?

I converted all my music from FLAC to ALAC, so I have two folders:

- E:\Data\flac\Albums\Tool\1993-Undertow\01-Intolerance.flac
- E:\Data\alac\Albums\Tool\1993-Undertow\01-Intolerance.m4a

I want Winmerge, or some other tool, to exclude the extensions and just compare the file names.

Comment: One possible (but somewhat roundabout) solution could be to create two text files, each containing the directory listing of one of the dirs, but without the file extensions. Then you can compare the text files as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it cannot.

However, you can use e.g. a PowerShell script (`[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(…)` or `[IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(…)` come to mind) to make the filenames in (copies of) the 2 folders the same, then you can compare folders with Winmerge.

But, should you use such a script, then you might as well just compare the folders directly from within the script if it is only to compare filenames…